# Bind objects to XAML collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

Is it possible to use binding to add objects to a XAML collection.

something like

```
<x:Array Type="sys:Int32">
   <Binding Source="obj", Path="Prop1"/>
   <Binding Source="obj", Path="Prop2"/>
</x:Array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the target of a data binding must be a dependency property and an element of a collection is not a property.

I can think of two workarounds, but both are ugly and I wouldn't use any of them:

1. You can create a `MarkupExtention` that will create a collection with whatever you want, you can even create one that create a collection from bindings, but the syntax will be very strange and the collection content won't be updated from the binding source.
2. You can also create a new collection class that inherits from `DependencyObject` and have dependecy properties for elements in teh collection (properties e0, e1, e2 ... that will update the contant of the collection when set).

I would try to find a way to accomplish what you want to do without filling a collection from data binding.